# quantmod in R: too many open files

Tags: r, quantmod

Who is opening the "files" and is not closing?

```
     library(quantmod)
     nyse.symbols<-stockSymbols("NYSE")
     nasdaq.symbols<-stockSymbols("NASDAQ")
     sym<-c(nasdaq.symbols$Symbol,nyse.symbols$Symbol)
     lapply(sym, function(x) {cat(x,sep="\n");tryCatch(getSymbols(x,from=Sys.Date()-365),error=function(e) e,warning=function(e) e);closeAllConnections()})/ 
     symbols <- sym[sym %in% ls()]
     for(i in symbols) {
       wfile <- file(paste("../data/",as.character(i),".txt",sep=""),open="wt")
       write.table(as.data.frame(get(i)), file=wfile,row.names=TRUE)
       close(wfile)
     }
```

Unfortunately, this simple code does not complete successfully with an error "too many open files".

Any help here? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more careful about your connections. Open one, use it, close it.

See `help(Connections)` -- and they are used everywhere for file access, data access, ...  But there is not reason why you can't access a few thousand symbols. But managed your resources.

Comment: I would do that, as i am trying to do for my file access. I think, this is happening in quantmod::getSymbols() (url connections) and i tried to see internals of it, however, being an R beginner, I had no luck. You might assume that's been done in getSymbols() carefully. What am i missing here? Also when i query for connections, it seems no connections open in my local scope to close them. I feel it is so deep in the code of quantmod.

Comment: There are different ways to get the data, starting with the code in the tseries package. Maybe try something else if you think quantmod is at fault.